# Get Data of online API

Tags: c#, api, http, httpwebrequest, discosweb

I want to download data of this website into a json file but as I am quite new to coding with C# I cant manage to get the data. I want to get Data of https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int/api/objects the authorization via token works but I dont know how I can send a request so the server gives me a json back and I cant find a solution online. I cant give you a screenshot of the API because you have to be logged in to see it. Plz ask me for detailed information if you can help me. Thank you realy for trying.

The code I want to run is here.

```
class Program
    {
        static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/vnd.api+json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("my_token");

            var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(client.BaseAddress);

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var streamReaderResult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Status https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int : " + httpResponse.StatusCode);
        }
}
```

Comment: Please describe the current behavior and any errors you received.

Comment: You are mixing different APIs. To use HttpClient [see this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var url = "https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int/api/objects";
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";

httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic XXXx";
httpRequest.ContentType = "";
httpRequest.Headers["Content-Length"] = "0";


var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine(httpResponse.StatusCode);
```

Where *XXXx* is user:password in base64.

Comment: You shouldn't add authorization headers like that really, you should probably do it through the `HttpClient` and `DefaultRequestHeaders`, it does a lot of validation on what you set them to

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic implementation for making that API call to get the JSON result. You will need to parse that JSON into something other than a string but I'll assume you can handle that part.

This uses `System.Net.HttpClient` which is the modern HTTP api provided by .NET. Its operations are `async` so hopefully your code is or can be written to properly await async operations.

```
//Someplace convenient, create a shared HttpClient to avoid
//creating and disposing for each request.
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
string data = await GetObjects(client);


//Example implementation
public async Task<string> GetObjects(HttpClient client)
{
    string url = "https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int/api/objects";
    using (HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
    {
        msg.Headers.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "your personal access token here");

        using (var result = await client.SendAsync(msg))
        {
            string content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return content;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*While I may be a month late, I've actually developed an SDK for this particular API.*

So, if you use [this SDK](https://github.com/hughesjs/DiscosWebSdk) it's pretty simple to do what you want. You can essentially forget about handling anything HTTP related, my SDK abstracts all of that away.

For example, to fetch Sputnik's data (which has an ID of 1) you'd run.

```cs
HttpClient innerClient = new();
innerClient.BaseAddress = "https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int/api/"
innerClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new("bearer", yourApiKey);
DiscosClient client = new();

DiscosObject sputnik = await client.GetSingle<DiscosObject>("1");
```

If you're using ASP.NET, [there's a set of DI extensions](https://github.com/hughesjs/DiscosWebSdk/blob/master/src/DiscosWebSdk/DiscosWebSdk/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjectionExtensions.cs) that can actually set it all up for you, so you can skip the first three lines.

If you do choose to use it, please let me know, as it would be nice knowing my SDK is getting some use. If you have any issues, please just reach out through the GitHub issues page and I'll try to help!

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this. The Database has much to play with and I will use your solution in the future. My current solution was the python script provided by ne ESA but your is more handy. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Thanks mate, don't forget to mark one of the answers as accepted by clicking the tick under the vote arrows of whichever answer you think was the most helpful btw